# Displaying the result of find / replace over multiple documents on bash

Tags: bash, shell, replace, find, xargs

I love to use the following command to do find / replace across multiple files in bash:

```
find -wholename "*.txt" -print | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

However, the above command process everything in silence, and sometimes I would like the above command to print all the changes it made in order to double check if I did everything correctly.  Can I know how should I improve the above command to allow it to dump such information?  I tried the `-v` argument in the `xargs` command but it gives me the `invalid option` error.

Comment: you could use emacs for that: [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](http://stackoverflow.com/q/270930/4279).

Comment: Thank you @J.F.Sebastian for the information, but I am a vim guy :~

Comment: You could remove `-i` and redirect everything to a file.  If everything is ok, execute your original command.  Also see [sed command in dry run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513623/sed-command-in-dry-run)

Comment: @devnull: thank you for the pointer.  I just tried it but seems like it outputs the whole files instead of just the replaced part @@", any idea of how to fix that @@"

Comment: To all awesome people who answered my question: I'm sorry that I have ran out of my votes today, I will vote up your answer once I can vote again :~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
find -wholename "*.txt" | xargs sed -n '/foo/p;s/foo/bar/gp'
```

What this will do is print the line that you wish to substitute and print the substitution in the next line.

You can use `awk` and get filename as well:

```
find -wholename "*.txt" | xargs awk '/foo/{print FILENAME; gsub(/foo/,"bar");print}'
```

To print entire file remove `print` and add `1`

```
find -wholename "*.txt" | xargs awk '/foo/{print FILENAME; gsub(/foo/,"bar")}1'
```

Regex will have to be modified as per your requirement and changes in-file is only available in `gawk version 4.1`

#### Test:

```
$ head file*
==> file1 <==
,,"user1","email"
,,"user2","email"
,,"user3","email"
,,"user4","email"

==> file2 <==
,,user2,location2
,,user4,location4
,,user1,location1
,,user3,location3
$ find . -name "file*" -print | xargs awk '/user1/{print FILENAME; gsub(/user1/,"TESTING");print}'
./file1
,,"TESTING","email"
./file2
,,TESTING,location1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But the output has the same issue as what my solution has, is there a way to know which file contains the output?

Comment: @keelar Added `awk` solution to print filename

Comment: Thank you, I am trying your solution, but  have syntax error the `print` right after `/foo/{`.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @keelar Added a sample test

Comment: Thank you for the sample test.  I tried the sample test but it seems that it does not actually change the files but a dry-run instead.  Is that what you mentioned at the end of your answer?

Comment: Yes, you can do `in-file` changes however that is only available in `awk` version 4.1

Comment: Too bad, mine is 3.1.5 :~  Suppose I have v4.1, can I know what regex should I put?

Comment: Sure, `find -wholename "*.txt" | xargs gawk -i inplace '/foo/{print FILENAME; gsub(/foo/,"bar");print}'`

Comment: Great thank !! I will +1 once I am able to, still struggling with one line solution runnable on my current environment :~~

Comment: @JS웃: `xargs` is not really needed. `find` have the same feature internally. See `-exec ... +`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the differences you can redirect the output of `sed` to a new file for every input file and compare it with the original.

```
for i in `find -wholename "*.txt"`; do
  sed 's/foo/bar/g' ${i} > ${i}.new;
  diff -u ${i} ${i}.new;
done
```

If the changes seem ok, move the new files to their original names.

```
for i in `find -wholename "*.new"` ; do
  mv ${i} ${i/.new};
done
```

Answer (score 1):

All can be done with [find](/questions/tagged/find) and [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). Only a little modification needed:

```
find -path "*.txt" -exec sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

This calls [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) with the max number of files (mind `+` at the end of `-exec`), so [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs) is not needed. In [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) `-i.bak` does an in-place-editing renaming the original file as `.bak`. So You can check the differences later if needed.

In `man find` one can read:

```
-wholename pattern
      See -path.    This alternative is less portable than -path.
```